# How can I implement this function of torch.where and torch.sqrt in a better way so that autograd works?

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd, automatic-differentiation

I have a class which has this forward operator:

```
def forward(self, x):
    r = torch.sqrt(x[:, 0:1]**2 + x[:, 1:2]**2)    
    value = torch.where(r <= 1, torch.sqrt(1.-r**2), -1)
    return value
```

This causes a problem with NaNs when it comes to taking gradients.

To circumvent this, one can use:

```
def forward(self, x):
    i = x[:, 0:1]**2 + x[:, 1:2]**2
    r = torch.sqrt(torch.relu(i))
    alternative=torch.sqrt(torch.relu(1.-r**2))
    value = torch.where(r <= 1, alternative, -1)

    return value
```

This gets rid of the NaN problems. Is there a better way to do this (with minimal changes to the original code if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use clamp to make the Nan values equal to zero.

```py
def forward2(x):
    r = torch.sqrt(x[:, 0:1] ** 2 + x[:, 1:2] ** 2)
    r = torch.clamp(r, 0.0, 1.0)  # Only one additional line
    value = torch.where(r <= 1, torch.sqrt(1.0 - r**2), -1)
    return value
```

Test with batch size of 5 and normal input:

Without clamp:

```
tensor([[-0.0069, -0.0278],
        [ 0.0203, -0.0501],
        [ 0.0126, -0.0309],
        [    nan,     nan],
        [    nan,     nan]])
```

With clamp:

```
tensor([[-0.0069, -0.0278],
        [ 0.0203, -0.0501],
        [ 0.0126, -0.0309],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000]])
```

Comment: But isn't it always the case that `r <=1`, because you clamped it? So no component of value will ever be -1?

Comment: Yes but the gradient is correct. Do you want to preserve the value of -1?

Comment: If it's possible yes. Let me wait and see if there are other solutions before accepting.

Comment: The best I found is the code you wrote: filtering first (with relu) and then applying 1-sqrt. It is the way suggested in [jax documentation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#gradients-contain-nan-where-using-where)